# read value from update() static on another class

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have problem because I can't read a static value added to Uptade() and use it.

**Rock**

```
[Header("Points")]
    public TextMeshProUGUI points;
    public static int point;


 private void Start()
    {
        points = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
       
    }


 void Update()
    {
        Move(); 
    }



void Move()
    {
       
        

point += 1;
        Debug.Log(point);


    }
```

**Points**

```
 [Header("Points")]
    public TextMeshProUGUI points;
    public  Rock countPoint;
    
  
    void Start()
    {
        
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
        Debug.Log("points" +  countPoint.point);
        
        
    }
```

I want to see this point in class **points**. If i will delete static then debug showing just 0.
Can you show me how to do it in correct way in full example ? or reedit my code.

Comment: you need Rock.point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access a [static member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) by using an object reference.
Instead of using an instance of the object:

```cs
Debug.Log("points" +  countPoint.point);
```

You should be using using the class to call the field:

```cs
Debug.Log("points" +  Rock.point);
```

Answer (score 1):

Static variables/functions can directly be accessed by class name.
So, Rock.point would do.